# how to upload form we created in infopath 2013 to sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

how we can create a form by Microsoft InfoPath 2013 and publish it in SharePoint 2013 in an easy way and make connect between the database in SQL server and InfoPath form to give users good information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Mathew has explained how to prepare your environment to use InfoPath path.

**Regarding creating a connection to SQL database from InfoPath,**

You have two options:

- Create a direct SQL data connection as shown below.

[image]

- Or Create a web service that receives your data from your view. You can check the detail steps with image at [InfoPath and Web Service data connection](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jannemattila/2007/01/21/infopath-and-web-service-data-connection/)

Comment: this all i want to know

Answer (score 3):

1- Make sure States Service is started.  Go to Central Administration --> click Application Management --> under Service Application section --> click Manage Service Application

2- If you don’t see State Service in the list, go to Central Admin --> click Configuration Wizard --> click Launch the Farm Configuration Wizard--> click Start the Wizard --> Select State Service and click OK.

Step 1: To create the InfoPath Form, open InfoPath Designer 2013 and under Available Form Templates, select Blank Form and click the Design Form button.

look at these links:

[Click](http://www.appvity.com/blogs/post/2013/06/16/How-to-configure-and-publish-InfoPath-to-SharePoint-2013.aspx)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HSyrqbgLdbs

Comment: that's good , I know how to create info path form but my issue was related to  connect to SQL database anyway thank you !